# Does Google Chrome work with Selenium IDE (as Firefox does)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium-ide

I can't find an equivalent of Selenium IDE that works with Chrome.

Does anyone know how to use Selenium IDE with Chrome instead of Firefox? Or is there an alternative tool which works with Chrome?

Comment: I tried testim.io as an alternative and liked it so much I joined the company :D That supports Firefox though it's a commercial product so it's more suited to companies rather than individuals.

Comment: There is now a [Selenium IDE extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd) for Chrome.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

artejera, do you mean Selenium as plugin to your browser (Selenium IDE)?
Here is [something](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) for automation in Google Chrome.

But if you want to work with Selenium RC, just set up browser in your test script. There is setBrowser() method in Selenium.

Comment: "just set up browser in your test script" - how do I do that?

Comment: @whamsicore it's complicated. Try the Selenium Guidebook for step-by-step instructions  https://seleniumguidebook.com/

Comment: You didn't really answer his question. His question was specifically about how to use Selenium IDE on Chrome (since it's not officially supported). In your answer you essentially said "screw selenium, use this other thing instead". Your second line is basically applicable only when we're running the code that's already written. OP's problem is writing the script itself.

Answer (score 10):

you can use Google chrome extensions like imacros, scirocco on chrome 21 or later versions. they are similar to selenium IDE for Firefox. Scirocco seems to be new with some limitations like navigation is not supported. So, I recommend 'imacros', seems very close to selenium.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to harness Selenium IDE record & playback capabilities for Chrome browser there is an equivalent extension for Chrome called Scirocco.
You can add it to Chrome by visiting here using your Chrome browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/scirocco

Scirocco is created by Sonix Asia and is not as polished as Selenium IDE for Firefox. It is in fact quite buggy in places. But it does what you ask.

Answer (score 5):

No, Google Chrome does not work with Selenium IDE. As Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin it works only with FF.

According to your last portion of question: Or is there any alternative tool which can work with Chrome? The possible answer is as follows:

You can use Sahi with Chrome. Sahi Test Automation tool supports Chrome, Firefox and IE. You can visit for details:

http://sahi.co.in/

Comment: this owuld be more useful if it wasn't so expensive, and if it was actually a browser plugin

Answer (score 4):

A couple of months ago, Micro Focus released a free tool that allows you to record Selenium scripts in Chrome and Firefox. It's called Silk WebDriver, you can download it for free from https://www.microfocus.com/products/silk-portfolio/silk-webdriver/

*Disclaimer: I work for Micro Focus.*

Answer (score 1):

There is not a Google Chrome extension comparable to Selenium IDE.

[Scirocco](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scirocco-recorder-for-chr/ibclajljffeaafooicpmkcjdnkbaoiih?hl=en) is only a partial (and reportedly unreliable) implementation.

There is another plugin, the [Bug Buster Test Recorder](https://bugbuster.com/test-recorder/), but it only works with their service.  I don't know it's effectiveness.

Sahi and TestComplete can also record, but neither are free, and are not browser plugins.

[iMacros](http://imacros.net/browser/cr/welcome) is a plugin that allows record and playback, but is not geared towards testing, and is not compatible with Selenium.

It sounds like there is a demand for a tool like this, and Firefox is becoming unsupported by Selenium.  So, while I know Stack Overflow isn't the forum for this, anyone interested in helping make it happen, let me know.

I'd be interested in what the limitations are and why it hasn't been done.  Is it just that the official Selenium team doesn't want to support it, or is there a technical limitation?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot record tests using the Selenium IDE in Chrome (or any other browser other than FF), you can run them (from the IDE) in Chrome, IE and other browsers using the Webdriver playback feature of Selenium 2 IDE.  Tests will need to be recorded and launched from FF - Chrome will launch before the first step of the test is executed. Instructions for setup and test execution are [here](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/02/18/webdriver-playback-in-selenium-ide-is-here/) and [here](http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-ide-browsers-webdriver-playback/).  You will need to install Selenium 2 IDE (if you haven't already done so) and the Chrome Webdriver Server executable - both are available for download on the Selenium HQ website.

NOTE:  If the above meets your needs, you may also want to consider just converting all your tests to Selenium Webdriver (which means they would be all code and no longer run from the Selenium IDE).  This would be a better solution from the perspective of test maintenance and simplicity of execution.  The Selenium documentation (on the Selenium website) has more information on the process to convert Selenium IDE tests to Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

See Scirocco Recorder For Chrome. It does IDE recording for Selenium 2 on Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scirocco-recorder-for-chr/ibclajljffeaafooicpmkcjdnkbaoiih

Comment: I think this is a good answer to the question.  But the application is not very good and you are far better off using the Firefox version if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi . This is available as nuget package in visual studio environment. Please let me know if you need more information as I have used it. URL can be found [Link to nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver)

You can also find some information here. [Blog with more details](http://prathapkudupublog.com/search?q=selenium)